# TigerVNC: Keyboard shortcut to lose focus in full-screen mode

Tags: vnc, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to lose focus of a TigerVNC viewer window in full-screen mode so that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used to switch windows of the host system?

I'm looking for something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> in Hyper-V VM viewer or <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> in VirtualBox.

I'm aware of sequence <kbd>[Menu key]</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> allowing to escape full-screen mode however it's a bit cumbersome.

Or possibly is there a way to define such keyborad shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

The F8 key is made for that, it open a menu, then choose `"Release Pointer and Keyboard"` to release the input focus and now you can alt tab, just click inside the VNC window if you want to focus again.

Comment: Hi, key F8 does nothing for me. The menu key (mapped to Pause key) causes the menu to pop up https://imgur.com/IT9aEfB . However there is no menu option "Release Pointer and Keyboard"? I use version 1.12.0. How can I get to the "Release Pointer and Keyboard"?